# full information of files and folders in QSortFilterProxyModel items

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I am using QSortFilterProxyModel in QTreeView for exploring all the files and folders of a directory. Its working fine.  but my problem is when i click on any of the item of QTreeView. I am not able to get its information like full path. Can anyone please tell me how to get its full path of the file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the full path with the following way. First you need to track mouse clicks on the `QTreeView` with connecting the `clicked()` signal to the appropriate slot:

```
connect(treeview, SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex &)), this, SLOT(onItemClicked(const QModelIndex &));
```

In your slot you can call the helper function that will return the full path of the clicked tree node:

```
void TreeView::onItemClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QString path = fullPath(index);
    // ..
}

QString TreeView::fullPath(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QString path('/');
    QModelIndex parent = index;
    while (parent.isValid()) {
        path.prepend('/' + parent.data().toString());
        parent = parent.parent();
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: Hi Vanhancho, one more thing i want to ask, In my Qtreeview, on Double click event on its items of treeview single click event also generates. I want only double click event. Please help me how to stop it for entering in single event slot. Thanks